# Angular 2 unit test: declare HTTP mocking globally

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I write test cases in angular 2.I want to know how following thing done. please help me.

- How to define Mocking (Http, router) globally.
- How to call common beforeEach() in every test cases.

My code which i want to common.

**common.ts**

```
  /* this used for route Mocking
   * */
  let mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
  }
  /*
   *  Response Url
   * */
  let metaUrl = {
    LOGIN: '/operator/login',
    META_API: '/meta-api'
  };

  let subject:GlobalUtils = null;
  let backend:MockBackend = null;
  let http:Http = null;
  /*
   *  The beforeEach function is called once before each spec in the describe in which it is called
   * */
  beforeEach(()=>TestBed.configureTestingModule({

    providers: [
      GlobalUtils,
      BaseRequestOptions,
      MockBackend,
      {
        provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter
      },
      {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: function (backend:ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions:BaseRequestOptions) {
          return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
        },
        deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
      },
    ]
  }));

  beforeEach(inject([GlobalUtils, MockBackend, Http], (_globalUtils:GlobalUtils, mockBackend:MockBackend, _http:Http) => {
    subject = _globalUtils;
    backend = mockBackend;
    http = _http;
  }));
```

Reason behind this I exactly this in another spec.ts file for write test case.

here is my spec.ts files

**1.spec.ts**

```
import {Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, ConnectionBackend} from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {TestBed, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {GlobalUtils} from '../global.utils.ts';
import { Constant } from '../constant'

describe('Global Utils : Meta urls API', () => {

  /* this used for route Mocking
   * */
  let mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
  }
  /*
   *  Response Url
   * */
  let metaUrl = {
    LOGIN: '/operator/login',
    META_API: '/meta-api'
  };

  let subject:GlobalUtils = null;
  let backend:MockBackend = null;
  let http:Http = null;
  /*
   *  The beforeEach function is called once before each spec in the describe in which it is called
   * */
  beforeEach(()=>TestBed.configureTestingModule({

    providers: [
      GlobalUtils,
      BaseRequestOptions,
      MockBackend,
      {
        provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter
      },
      {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: function (backend:ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions:BaseRequestOptions) {
          return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
        },
        deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
      },
    ]
  }));

  beforeEach(inject([GlobalUtils, MockBackend, Http], (_globalUtils:GlobalUtils, mockBackend:MockBackend, _http:Http) => {
    subject = _globalUtils;
    backend = mockBackend;
    http = _http;
  }));

  /*
  * This Test case is check Response of getMetaUrls function
  * getMetaUrls must return response
  * */
  it('Should have get Meta urls', (done) => {
    // HTTP Mocking
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection:MockConnection)=> {
      let options = new ResponseOptions({
        body: JSON.stringify(metaUrl),status: 200
      });
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));
    });
    /*
     * we mock http get method
     * */
    http
      .get(Constant.metaUrl)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        subject.getMetaUrls();
        expect(Constant.saveUrl).toEqual(metaUrl);
        done();
      });

  });

  /*
  * This Test case is check empty response and redirect to error page
  * getMetaUrls must return empty response
  * */
  it('Should have get Empty Meta urls data', (done) => {
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection:MockConnection)=> {
      let options = new ResponseOptions({
        body: JSON.stringify(''), status: 200
      });
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));
    });

    http
      .get(Constant.metaUrl)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        subject.getMetaUrls();
        expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['page-error']);
        done();
      });
  });
```

**2.spec.ts**

```
describe('Authentication test',()=>{

});
```

2.spec file blank now because I want to use **common.ts** function in this file and I want to know how.